# How to can i make this?

Tags: visual-studio

I am a new member.

I want to know that "How Can I make this box in visual studio?"

[Attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcQ2z.png)

Comment: what do you mean by make it in visual studio? are you trying to add a windows control to a windows application? or WPF? or is that an asp.net? or what? please make you question more clear

Comment: also please change your question tag to meet your question subject and details, VBA is visual basic for application tag

Answer (score 0):

It's called a list view. Make sure you set the mode to details and add columns!

Comment: How to can add those text "size,status" (given in the pic at the top) ?

Comment: That's the Column Text fields.